# How to write a big amount of multipage TIFF files?

Tags: python-2.7, mahotas

Hi everybody from a beginner in Python. I try to convert a huge file of raw video data into multiple multipage TIFF files by using the "freeimage.write_multipage()" function of the freeimage package from the Mahotas library (Python 2.7). Unfortunately, it seems that this "very easy to use" function doesn't release memory when running the script. So, my script works fine for small input raw files (less than 1 GB) but crashes with bigger files (a 3 GB input file crashes with Win XP pro 32 - ram 3.2 GB). My goal is to convert input files up to 1.5 TB.

When running my script, the Windows Task manager shows an increase of the used ram, output file after output file until the crash which release all the used ram. An extract of the reported error is: "... RuntimeError : mahotas.freeimage: FreeImage error: Memory allocation failed..."

From Stackoverflow, I saw different advices for building multipages TIFF files with using scripts in Image Magic or Irfanview but I think it's impossible for my needs (I have thousands of pictures to assemble). 
Thank you for any help.